# Magento 2 - Move the afterMethods item (Discount) before Place Order Button

Tags: magento2

I would like to move the **afterMethods** xml item which contains the Discount Code and Gift Card code under the **billing-step** in the `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/checkout_index_index.xml`, so that it is displayed before the Place Order Button on checkout page.

Basically I want to have the Place order Button as the last component on the page.

Comment: Could this be implemented to move the estimated total field that is at the top of the page to just above the place order button?

Answer (score 3):

I have modified the above answer to make it more easy to learn.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

Use the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>         
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and for the second file

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_SalesRule/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

use the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: After doing this the sales rule discount code form is displaying on the shipping step. What's the best way to get rid of it there?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I needed to disable the afterMethods component from billing step. 
To do so I added this code in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` under checkout > children node.

```
    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
        </item>         
    </item>
</item>
```

Then in the `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_SalesRule/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file update the code to set the `discount` node as child of `before-place-order` node.

```
<item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Same thing can be done for gift card.