# Change Coupon Code Position in Checkout

Tags: magento2

I want to change the position of the coupon code in Magento2 checkout to the top above the address form field. I know the two checkout_index_index.xml file in magento_checkout and magento_sales_rules but i don't know how to change them for the sort order.

Comment: You can refer to my answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166460/magento-2-move-the-aftermethods-item-discount-before-place-order-button/174409#174409

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it like this.
make original plugin. for Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor

```
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
    ) {

    // copy buff
    $discount_mstsrc = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']
    ['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']
    ['afterMethods']['children']['discount'];
    // del
    unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']
    ['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']
    ['afterMethods']['children']['discount']);
    // copy to
    $dstsrc =& $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']
    ['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']
    ['beforeMethods']['children'];

    $dstsrc['discount'] = $discount_mstsrc;

    return $jsLayout;
}
```

Comment: is it working or not mention it.

Comment: it works on Magento2 at CE 2.1.6