# Magento 2 : I need to move coupon form in checkout page to the page top

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to move the coupon form in checkout before the Payment method details.
I tried through override of `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template - payment.html`

But it didn't affected ,is there any other ways to solve this requirement ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do it via XML config. In your case, we need to disable the default coupon. And, add it to `beforeMethods` region. For example, in your module:

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!--Disable default coupon-->
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <!--Add new coupon to beforeMethod region-->
                                                        <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[Image demo]

[image]

Comment: Yes i got same method here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166460/magento-2-move-the-aftermethods-item-discount-before-place-order-button/174409#174409 thanks for your answer

Comment: yeah! I think my code will work perfectly for your requirement.