# Magento2 - Move coupon code section inside or before shipping method section

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am using `Magento2.3.3` And I want to move coupon code section before shipping method using `checkout_index_index.xml`. 
[image]

Comment: add screenshot for the same

Comment: @Hiren I have screen shot . Plz review it

Comment: Are you using any third-party checkout extension on your Magento instance or its default Magento checkout?

Comment: @Jaimin Yes (https://marketplace.magento.com/onestepcheckout-iosc.html). But I am able to move coupon code on before payment section using  checkout_index_index.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by the below code. Create a new checkout_index_index.xml in your module and add the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="captcha" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/captcha</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">captcha</item>
                                                                            <item name="formId" xsi:type="string">sales_rule_coupon_request</item>
                                                                            <item name="configSource" xsi:type="string">checkoutConfig</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

It will look like below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jaimin After added above code coupon code section not moving .(I have just try ) While I have used https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219523/14537 code on checkout xml then coupon section is move on above payment section. Can review this and we try to solve out this problem

Comment: Please check with the updated code, it will remove the default discount section from payment and add it to the shipping section. If it's still not working, please provide your checkout_index_index.xml file code to review.

Comment: Updated code working but coupon section showing on Shipping address section I want to show on before shipping method. https://ibb.co/xJZPnv0

Comment: If you update 'before-form' with 'before-shipping-method-form' in above code, it will work. Please try above code

Comment: Thank you for you support. Code is working fine

Comment: I am try to show coupon section above shipping method label but success   https://ibb.co/NY3J8rD

Comment: That looks great @Shorabh

Comment: Client wants to show there @Jaimin .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104876/discussion-between-shorabh-and-jaimin-sutariya).